# How to identify conflicts or overlaps in multiple conditions?

Tags: java, c#

How do we know if two or multiple conditions have overlaps or conflicts (intersection)?

When do filtering on a list or data-set, is there any good way to identify any overlaps or conflicts in the conditions?

For instance, I have a list of conditions going to be used on a data list, one of the conditions might be if (a > 3), then do something or return true, another condition a < 5, then do something else or return false, etc..

For this scenario, we want to send alert to user that there is conflict in the input conditions.

Any good ideas?

Comment: A first thought: complete the condition.  In computer arithmetic, numbers have limits, they are not infinite.  `a<5` means `a<5 && a>=Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  Then I would test each range for overlap.

Comment: Usually you'll find those easily via practice and also with some test cases having corner scenarios